# Why metric defined on $\mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^2$ by $(a,b)\mapsto | a_1 - b_1| +| a_2 - b_2| $ is known as taxicab metric?

Tags: metric-spaces

$\mathbb{R}^2$ with the function defined on $\mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^2$ by $(a,b)\mapsto | a_1 - b_1| +| a_2 - b_2|  $ where $a = (a_1, a_2)$ and $b = (b_1, b_2)$ is a metric. I wonder why it is known as taxicab metric. Could anyone explain me?

Thank you very much

Comment: I know the metric as the _Manhatten_ metric, but it's the same. Thing is you only get these kind of streets afaik only in big American cities. Do you know the Paris metric?

Comment: @SimonMarkett I have never heard before about this metric but just now I goggled and got to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine a big city laid out so that the streets all run either north-south or east-west and are spaced at regular intervals. In order to go from one point to another by taxicab, you must travel along the streets, so you can only travel north-south or east-west. The distance travelled is therefore the sum of the north-south separation and the east-west separation between you and your destination. The taxicab metric is the distance **as the cab would travel** instead of the straight-line, or Euclidean distance distance. (The latter is sometimes described in English as **as the crow flies**, so we could call the Euclidean metric the *crow metric*, but no one does!)

Comment: Dear sir, I didn't this point;The distance travelled is therefore the sum of the north-south separation.....

Comment: @srijan: Look at [this picture](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/Manhattan_distance.svg): the green line shows the straight-line distance, and the red, blue, and yellow lines all show the taxicab distance, following the streets. Note that all three cover the same distance, $6$ blocks north-south and $6$ blocks east-west: the total is $12$ blocks, a north-south separation of $6$ blocks plus an east-west separation of $6$ blocks.

Comment: Wow that pic tells everything. I understand now.

Answer (score 4):

[A picture](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/Manhattan_distance.svg) is definitely the way to see this most easily. From a top down view the metric looks like a city, and the paths an object in this metric must take are the same as a taxicab must take in such a city (not being able to fly or drive through buildings for instance).

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that it reflects the distance between two points if you only travel parallel to the axes. So to get from $(7,3)$ to $(4,8)$ you first travel 3 units left to $(4,3)$ then 5 up to $(4,8)$, for a total distance of eight. Hence the distance is the sum of the vertical distance and the horizontal distance.

It's meant to be evocative of the distance a taxicab would travel in a city where streets are in a grid pattern, so that you can only get places by going, say, east-west or north-south, rather than travelling directly towards them.

Answer (score 3):

See
[image: HERE]
how the streets of Manhattan look, as opposed to other places nearby...

Comment: Thank you very much. I never thought of getting such a clear insight og taxicab metric. Thanks again.:)